# google app quickstart.php example how to change sheet

Tags: php, api

So i have run through the guide of how to read data from a google sheet using their API. All works fine until i want to read from any sheet other than the one given in the example.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php

is there something else that i need to change as when I update the spreadsheet id to one of mine i just get the following

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message   '{
  "error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Unable to parse range: Class Data!A2",
"errors": [
  {
    "message": "Unable to parse range: Class Data!A2",
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest"
  }
],
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys the issue was that i was declaring the range wrong problem now sorted.